# Can the compactification of a (co)tangent bundle equipped with Saski metric be viewed as a "Wick rotation"?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, mp.mathematical-physics

We can equip the (co)tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold (B,g) with a Saski metric $\hat{g}$ (see, for example, "On the geometry of tangent bundles" by Gudmunssun & Kappos) that looks like
\begin{equation*}
\hat{g} = \pi^*g\oplus g_V
\end{equation*}
where $\pi: T^{(*)}B \to B$ is the projection and $g_V$ is the metric on the vertical directions of the fibration. In certain cases (i.e. when $B$ is affine), we can compactify by taking the quotient of $T^{(*)}B$ by a (dual) lattice $\Gamma^{(*)}$ to obtain the non-singular torus fibrations $T^{(*)}B/\Gamma^{(*)} \to B$.

In physics, there is a (I don't know how well-defined) notion of "time-compactification" by passing from a Riemannian manifold $(M,\hat{g}_+)$ to a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $(M,\hat{g}_-)$ via a "Wick rotation" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation). In flat coordinates, if
\begin{equation*}
\hat{g}_+ = \sum_i dx_i^2 + \sum_j dy_j^2 \ ,
\end{equation*}
then a Wick rotation is equivalent to the procedure of substituting $y_j \to \sqrt{-1} y_j$ since
\begin{equation*}
\hat{g}_- = \sum_i dx_i^2 - \sum_j dy_j^2  \ .
\end{equation*}

I would like to know whether this can be related to the procedure of taking the alternative metric
\begin{equation}
\hat{g}' = \pi^*g\oplus (-1)g_V
\end{equation} 
on $T^{(*)}B$ and whether this can somehow be seen as equivalent to compactification by taking the quoitient with respect to $\Gamma^{(*)}$.

Comment: A couple of notes. Wick rotation does not _a priori_ have anything to do with compactification, though sometimes the two come together. You can find a mathematically precise notion of Wick rotation in this [answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/165317/2622). I'm not sure that what you are doing qualifies, as you are not doing an analytic continuation anywhere. Though, perhaps there is a way to reinterpret your construction in terms of complexification and analytic continuation.

Comment: @Igor, thanks for the link. Perhaps you could explain how your view of the Wick rotation presented there is ("sometimes") related to compactification. How does a noncompact submanifold get smoothly deformed to a compact submanifold of the complexification?

Comment: Simple. The complexification $M_\mathbb{C}$ is not unique. For example, the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}$ embeds into both $\mathbb{C}$ (with a non-compact Wick rotation) and $\mathbb{C}/i\mathbb{Z}$ (with a compact Wick rotation).